# Loading data into redshft database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have five JSON files in one folder in amazon s3. I am trying to load all five files from s3 into redshift using copy command. I am getting an error while loading one file from s3 to redshift. Is there any way in redshift to skip loading that file and load the next file.

Comment: is full file is corrected or there are some records having data issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`MAXERROR`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-maxerror) parameter in the `COPY` command to increase the number of errors permitted. This will skip over any **lines** that produce errors.

Then, use the [STL_LOAD_ERRORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STL_LOAD_ERRORS.html) table to view the errors and diagnose the data problem.